# Get Humanoid Motion data in npy format

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, motion, pybullet

I am using pybullet as 3d engine to my project of redoing my own algo, that make a humanoid learn to do some motion. for my algo i need a dataset of motion, like deepmimic and amp algo need. so i need an npy file that contain all the data about the joints of the humanoid in motion, and a way to know the name of the joints, to be able to identify .
python version = 39
Os = windows 64

Comment: to make a npy file you have first make a numpy array with the right shape and data.  Then `np.save` it.

Comment: this is not my problem, i need to find a way to convert motion file (fbx) to npy. Or i need to find some alredy made npy file for some humanoid motion.